# How to copy installed gems to another docker image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I tried Docker multi-stage build to create a clean image for rails production runtime.
I made Dockerfile like below

```
# Build image
FROM scardon/ruby-node-alpine:2.4.2 AS build-env

COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies PACKAGES && \
    gem install bundler && \
    bundle install && \
    bundle exec assets:precompile && \
    bundle exec assets:sync

# Runtime image
FROM ruby:2.4.2-alpine3.6

COPY . .
# $BUNLE_PATH is set to /usr/local/bundle in both images.
COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build-env /root/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-abcdef123456.json /root/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-abcdef123456.json
```

But in below image, `bundle check` says that gems, which needs native extension build, is not installed. `bundle doctor` outputs is like below

```
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
Ignoring byebug-9.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 9.0.6
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.3
Ignoring ffi-1.9.18 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.18
Ignoring json-2.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 2.1.0
Ignoring mysql2-0.4.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.4.8
Ignoring nio4r-2.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.1.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.0
Ignoring oj-3.3.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine oj --version 3.3.4
Ignoring puma-3.9.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.9.1
Ignoring rainbow-2.2.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rainbow --version 2.2.2
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.5
The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.3, but you are currently running 1.15.4.
To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
The following gems are missing
 * nokogiri (1.8.0)
 * nio4r (2.1.0)
 * websocket-driver (0.6.5)
 * bindex (0.5.0)
 * debug_inspector (0.0.3)
 * binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
 * byebug (9.0.6)
 * ffi (1.9.18)
 * rainbow (2.2.2)
 * json (2.1.0)
 * mysql2 (0.4.8)
 * oj (3.3.4)
 * puma (3.9.1)
Install missing gems with `bundle install`
```

But in `$BUNDLE_PATH`, these gems are there.
What is needed to tell `bundler` that dependencies are satisfied?

Thank you

(Sorry for my poor English.)

Answer (score -2):

You can share the data by creating a persistent Ruby gems container. Review the details below;

https://www.healthcareblocks.com/blog/persistent-ruby-gems-docker-container

Comment: This page was removed at some point before 14 February 2019, when the site was crawled by the Wayback Machine (also known as web.archive.org).

More recent, existing pointers would be greatly appreciated.